# Difference between mod and rem operators in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I came across these statements in VHDL programming and could not understand the difference between the two operators mod and rem

```
    9 mod 5
    (-9) mod 5
    9 mod (-5)
    9 rem 5
    (-9) rem 5
    9 rem (-5)
```

Comment: http://computer-programming-forum.com/42-vhdl/6f9dce015f5ce94f.htm

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A way to see the different is to run a quick simulation in a test bench, for
example using a process like this:

```
process is
begin
  report "  9  mod   5  = " & integer'image(9 mod 5);
  report "  9  rem   5  = " & integer'image(9 rem 5);
  report "  9  mod (-5) = " & integer'image(9 mod (-5));
  report "  9  rem (-5) = " & integer'image(9 rem (-5));
  report "(-9) mod   5  = " & integer'image((-9) mod 5);
  report "(-9) rem   5  = " & integer'image((-9) rem 5);
  report "(-9) mod (-5) = " & integer'image((-9) mod (-5));
  report "(-9) rem (-5) = " & integer'image((-9) rem (-5));
  wait;
end process;
```

It shows the result to be:

```
# ** Note:   9  mod   5  =  4
# ** Note:   9  rem   5  =  4
# ** Note:   9  mod (-5) = -1
# ** Note:   9  rem (-5) =  4
# ** Note: (-9) mod   5  =  1
# ** Note: (-9) rem   5  = -4
# ** Note: (-9) mod (-5) = -4
# ** Note: (-9) rem (-5) = -4
```

[Wikipedia - Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)
has an elaborate description, including the rules:

- mod has sign of divisor, thus `n` in `a mod n`
- rem has sign of dividend, thus `a` in `a rem n`

The `mod` operator gives the residue for a division that rounds down (floored division), so `a = floor_div(a, n) * n + (a mod n)`.  The advantage is that `a mod n` is a repeated sawtooth graph when `a` is increasing even through zero, which is important in some calculations.

The `rem` operator gives the remainder for the regular integer division `a / n` that rounds towards 0 (truncated division), so `a = (a / n) * n + (a rem n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For equal sign:
9/5=-9/-5=1.8 gets 1 
9 mod 5 = 9 rem 5
-9 mod -5 = -9 rem -5
-----------------------------------------
For unequal signs:
9/-5 = -9/5 = -1.8
In "mod" operator : -1.8 gets -2
In "rem" operator : -1.8 gets -1
----------------------------------------
example1: (9,-5)
9 = (-5*-2)-1  then:  (9 mod -5) = -1
9 = (-5*-1)+4  then:  (9 rem -5) = +4
----------------------------------------
example2: (-9,5)
-9 = (5*-2)+1  then:  (-9 mod 5) = +1
-9 = (5*-1)-4  then:  (-9 rem 5) = -4
----------------------------------------
example3: (-9,-5)
-9 = (-5*1)-4  then:  (-9 mod -5) = -4
-9 = (-5*1)-4  then:  (-9 rem -5) = -4
----------------------------------------
example4: (9,5)
9 = (5*1)+4  then:  (9 mod 5) = +4
9 = (5*1)+4  then:  (9 rem 5) = +4
```