# VHDL -1 rem 4 returns 3, why?

Tags: vhdl, arithmetic-expressions

Take the following VHDL code:

```
to_signed(-1, 32) rem to_signed(4, 32)
```

From what I understand from various sources and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848879/difference-between-mod-and-rem-operators-in-vhdl) this should produce the result -1, but it returns 3, just as `mod`. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: make this an assert or report in an [MCVE] including the library/use clauses.

Comment: It does produce the result -1 : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/42R8 . Please do as Brian asks.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh no it doesn't...

As an MCVE :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity rem_tb is
end rem_tb;

architecture arch of rem_tb is
begin
    assert false report "Result : " & integer'image(to_integer(to_signed(-1, 32) 
                                    rem to_signed(4, 32))) severity NOTE;
end arch;
```

compiled with ghdl:

```
ghdl -a rem_tb.vhd
ghdl -e rem_tb
ghdl -r rem_tb
```

it replies

```
rem_tb.vhd:11:1:@0ms:(assertion note): Result : -1
```

So ... which simulator are you using? What does that simulator do with the MCVE?

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Vivado 2016.4 and actual hardware. The "rem" function from ieee.numeric_std does produce the correct value. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: ug901 v2016.4, Vivado Design Suite User Guide Synthesis, Chapter 4 VHDL Support, Table 4-10, VHDL Constructs and Support Status, VHDL Operators, rem "Supported if the right operand is a constant power of 2."  A [mcve] demonstrating the problem sounds in order.

Comment: From looking at Matthew Taylor's link and modifying Brian's code with an additional assert for mod, we see that the mod result is 3.

Comment: Then where are you getting a rem operator that doesn't produce -1?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I mean using the "rem" (with quotes) function as opposed to the rem operator, ie. "rem"(to_signed(-1, 32), to_signed(4, 32)).

Comment: @user1155120 That's probably my issue. Although a right operand of 4 ought to be supported I can't create an example that produces the same results in the simulator and on the hardware, apart from the mentioned "rem" function.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't include the detail about Vivado earlier. I was sure that I understand how the rem operator should work incorrectly and 3 is the proper result.

Comment: Both function call or binary operator form should call the same function and produce the same result - and do, in the above example. It's still unclear what you're REALLY doing and why you are seeing something different. Except for one warning bell ... "and actual hardware".Frankly, if you haven't simulated this first and got correct results, synthesis can take diabolical liberties to exploit mistakes elsewhere in your code to generate hardware that does just about anything or nothing at all.

Comment: I don't know what's going on in my design but at this point I don't have time to find it out in detail. I went with a divide-multiple-subtract workaround. For my use-case it's actually better since the cumulative latency of these operations after each other is smaller than that of a single mod or rem operation, if the right operand is a power of two. Which is curious is that on contrary what the Vivado docs say division with non power of two const right operands works as well (at least in the handful of cases I tested). Thank all of you again!